# Adding work item id by default in the related work items

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-workitem

Every time when I check-in the code in Visual Studio, I need to provide the product backlog item's work item id (task id) in the pending changes window's Related Work Items section.

If I'm working on a module for a week, on each check-in I need to provide the same work item id (at least 5 to 6 check-in in a day). It seems repeating of work.

Is there any possible way to add the work item id by default in the "Related Work Items" section in the Visual Studio settings?

[image: VS - Work items]

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and TFS 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's not able to do this. It will not cached the ID you previous entered.

Instead of entering ID, you could also drag work items here to link work item to check in.

[image]

Or you could do it the other way around, open the work item and add a link to your previous changeset.

1. Get the changeset ID by looking at the History of one of the changed files
2. Open the relevant work item
3. Select the Links tab
4. Click the Add button
5. Select "Changeset" from the Link type dropdown
6. Enter the changeset ID (from step 1) into the Changeset field, and click OK
7. Save the work item

After this the work item **will** also appear in the changeset's list of associated work items.

Comment: Thanks for the option to drag work item by the query result window.

Comment: There is an [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/444442/add-last-used-work-item.html) raised for the same in the developer community. As currently, there is no other option for my concern, so I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, that`s not possible. You may add all your changes to work item after your work will be done:
[image]

Comment: We have a check-in policy that work order id is mandatory for check-in. So link after check-in will not helpful in this case. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is my fantasy )). Try to create CodedUI test that checkings without you: [Walkthrough: Create, edit, and maintain a coded UI test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-editing-and-maintaining-a-coded-ui-test?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use a custom tool with TFS API like that: [How to checkin source code with work item associated using TFS API](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Checkin-Source-Code-65b278be).